# Is Gideon on The Flash and Gideon on Legends of Tomorrow same?

Tags: character, the-flash, legends-of-tomorrow, arrowverse

I've just started watching [Legends of Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_Tomorrow), and the time vessel's captain is aided by an AI called Gideon. Is that the same or different Gideon from the one in The Flash? Also, is the name a reference to [Gideon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gideon)?

Comment: What exactly does "the same" mean when dealing with an AI? They're still fundamentally code, so if you have two instances of that same code running, are they the same AI or are they different AIs because they'll have been exposed to different things?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I feel like this is an easy question to answer. Identical twins are biological examples of 'the same code' running in two different 'machines.' We don't consider twins to be the same human, despite their identical DNA.

Comment: Sorry, what I really meant by "same" is "same instance"

Comment: If i remember correctly Flash created Gideon.. The Gideon from the future I think is the same one used by Thawne and the Flash and oh maybe the Justice League too.. My head hurts.

Comment: Well, it is a different one in the sense that she has a different voice, since Morena Baccarin is a bit busy on *Gotham* at the moment, so they switched Gideon's voice out (on *Legends* and *The Flash* though, so it might be a new one, yet still the same instance on both shows)...

Comment: Gideon is like Siri. Better question, why is Rip using a what, 140 year old computer instead of something newer?

Comment: @cde Well, since it is clearly a different version, maybe this is *Gideon Ver. 95134.0* (or Barry cheated and built his first version after encountering her in the future and she herself is a paradox).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gideon is an interactive artificial consciousness.

Now, consider this scenario: You have an iPhone. Your friend also has an iPhone. Both of you use Siri on your phones.

Think of Gideon as Siri, from the Future. A lot of people probably use it.

The Gideon in S.T.A.R. Labs had a different voice than the one on board the Wave Rider. That's because they changed the voice actor due to a scheduling conflict.

It is however interesting to note that (in the context of canon) Rip Hunter's Gideon has a British accent, and since he is British, we can assume that Gideon can be programmed to speak with different accents. So his Gideon has that accent.

So, is it Gideon? Yes.

Is it the same Gideon from S.T.A.R. Labs that the Reverse Flash / Eobard Thawne / Professor Zoom had? No.

Comment: We see in later episodes that other Time Masters have different AIs, all with different names starting with the letter G. But it's a reasonable assumption that the name is customizable, like how Amazon Echo can be set to respond to either "Alexa" or "Amazon".

Answer (score -1):

How about this? The Gideon on the Wave Rider is the future version of the Gideon on the Flash, which is a future version of the Gideon that Thawne stole from the Wave Rider.  Kind of like when in the episode of Dr. Who where there was 3 Dr.'s. The oldest one programmed his sonic screw driver and the answer came up on the newest Dr.'s screw driver because it had calculated through all those years. Or not.

Answer (score -1):

They are the same AI, but different accent. I would say because Rip Hunter is British and therefore has a British Gideon.
Flash/Thawne is American and therefore an American version.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is the same gideon becouse in S2 thorn in on the ship looking for something.

I think he finds gideon and copies her base code and her info about the time line, but at the end of S2 thorn is killed so I think he makes a time remnet and gives sead remnet his gideon and leaves it for thorn in the flash.